# Shell Script Replace a Specified Column with sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a example dataset separated by semicolon as below;

```
123;IZMIR;ZMIR;123
abc;ANKAR;aaa;999
AAA;ZMIR;ZMIR;bob
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

I would like to replace values in a specified column. Lets say I want to change "ZMIR" AS "IZMIR" but only for the third column, the ones on the second column must stay the same.

Desired output is;

```
123;IZMIR;IZMIR;123
abc;ANKAR;aaa;999
AAA;ZMIR;IZMIR;bob
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

I tried;

```
sed 's/;ZMIR;/;IZMIR;/' file.txt
```

the problem is that it changes all the values on the file not just the 3rd one.

I also tried;

```
awk -F";" '{gsub("ZMIR",";IZMIR;",$2)}1'
```

and here it specifies the column but, it somehow adds spaces;

```
123 I;IZMIR; ZMIR 123
abc;ANKAR;aaa;999
AAA ;IZMIR; ZMIR bob
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

sed doesn't know about columns, awk does (but in awk they're called "fields"):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} $3=="ZMIR"{$3="IZMIR"} 1' file
```

Note that since the above is doing a literal string search and replace, you don't have to worry about regexp or backreference metacharacters in the search or replacement strings, unlike in a sed solution (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/1745001).

wrt what you tried previously with awk:

```
awk -F";" '{gsub("ZMIR",";IZMIR;",$2)}1'
```

That says: `find "ZMIR" in the 2nd semi-colon-separated field and replace it with ";IZMIR;" and also change every existing ";" on the line to a blank character`.

To learn awk, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: it works! thank you very much. Is it also possible to save the result or do I have to redirect it?

Comment: Gnu awk has a `-i inplace` option but in general `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` works just fine for every UNIX command.

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly know where the word to replace is located and how many of them are in that line you could use sed with something like:

```
sed '3 s/ZMIR/IZMIR/2'
```

With the 3 in the beginning you are selecting the third line and with the 2 in the end the second occurrence. However the awk solution is a better one. But just that you know how it works in sed ;)

Comment: it works only if you know exactly what and where it is int the file. If line is (ex:)`ddd;IZMIR;IZMIR;bad` it failed. and OP specify '*sample of data*' and '*replace values in a specified column*'

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^;]+/\n&\n/3;s/\nZMIR\n/IZMIR/;s/\n//g' file
```

Surround the required field by unique markers then replace the required string (plus markers) by the replacement string. Finally remove the unique markers.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl on Command Line**

**Input**

```
123;IZMIR;ZMIR;123  
000;ANKAR;aaa;999  
AAA;ZMIR;ZMIR;bob  
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

`$. == 1` means first **row**  it does the work only for this **row**  So second **row**  `$. == 2`
`$F[0]`   means first **column**   and it only does on this **column**  So fourth **column** `$F[3]`
`-a -F\;`  means that delimiter is `;`

**what you want**
`perl -a -F\; -pe 's/$F[0]/***/ if $. == 1' your-file`

**output**

```
***;IZMIR;ZMIR;123  
abc;ANKAR;aaa;999  
AAA;ZMIR;ZMIR;bob  
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

for **row == 2** and **column == 2**
`perl -a -F\; -pe 's/$F[1]/***/ if $. == 2' your-file`

```
123;IZMIR;ZMIR;123  
abc;***;aaa;999  
AAA;ZMIR;ZMIR;bob  
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

---

Also without `-a -F`
`perl -pe 's/123/***/ if $. == 1' your-file`

**output**

```
***;IZMIR;ZMIR;123  
abc;ANKAR;aaa;999  
AAA;ZMIR;ZMIR;bob  
BBB;ANKR;RRRR;ABC
```

---

If you want to edit you can add `-i` option that means **Edit in-place** And that's it, it simply find, replace and save in the same file
`perl -i -a -F\;` and so on

Answer (score -1):

You need to include some absolute references in the line:

- `^` for beginning of the line
- unequivocal separation pattern
- `^.*ZMIR` and `[^;]*;ZMIR` give different values where first take everything before ZMIR and `sed` take the longest possible

Specific

```
sed 's/^\([^;]*;[^;]*;\)ZMIR;/\1IZMIR;/' YourFile
```

generic where *Old* and *New* are batch variable (Remember, this is regex value so regex rules to apply like escaping some char)

```
#Old='ZMIR'
#New='IZMIR'

sed 's/^\(\([^;]*;\)\{2\}\)'${Old}';/\1'${New}';/' YourFile
```

In this simple case `sed` is an alternative, but `awk` is better for a complex or long line.